# Awk flow control in filtering data

Tags: bash, sed, scripting, awk

I have data structured in a file like this:

```
heading.o:
0000000000000000 T name_of_func1
0000000000000005 U name_of_func2
000000000000003d B name_of_func3
...
heading2.o:
0000000000000000 T name_of_func4
0000000000000000 T name_of_func5
...
heading3.o:
...
```

I want to get the headings, the symbols (T,U,B) and the function names. This is what I've got at the moment:

```
awk '/:$/{ print }' | sed 's/://' # get all the headings and get rid of ':'
```

But I don't really know how to make these sorts of conditionals. Could you please help?

--

General expected output:

```
 heading.o symbol(U/T/B) name_of_func
```

Real expected output:

```
 heading.o T name_of_func1
 heading.o U name_of_func2
 heading.o B name_of_func3
 heading2.o T name_of_func4
 heading3.o .......
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Do you like to list all the different func name? T U and B has different func

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use awk:

```
awk 'NF==1{sub(/:$/, ""); p=$1;next} NF==3{print p, $2, $3}' file
heading.o T name_of_func1
heading.o U name_of_func2
heading.o B name_of_func3
heading2.o T name_of_func4
heading2.o T name_of_func5
```

Comment: It is always better to show your expected input/output for a problem like this to get better answers on this forum.

Comment: Please, any ideas if the first column is missing time to time? So that there are no numbers and awk takes the symbol (T/U/B) as the first column?

Comment: so `0000000000000000` might be missing sometimes?

Comment: For that you can use: `awk 'NF==1{sub(/:$/, ""); p=$1;next} NF==3{print p, $2, $3;next} NF==2{print p, $1, $2}' file`

Comment: This might be shorter: `awk 'NF==1{sub(/:$/, ""); p=$1;next} NF>1{print p, $(NF-1), $NF;next}' file`

Comment: @anubhava The `next` statements are redundant in both solutions.

Comment: Agreed, next can be removed.